# METEOR fedora "Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat" mhen y try to do "meteor add-platform android"

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, angular-meteor

I cannot build my meteor app into Android.
I tried to make, but always have this error.
I tried to do `meteor add-platform android`, but it always gives me the following error.
Try to change the permissions of the folder to 777 and those of the `.meteor` and make a chown to my user to both folders but I always have the same error.

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat
>   '/workspace/meteorProject/socially/.meteor/local/dev_bundle'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
>       at statOrNull (/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.qtn91h++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:114:19)
>       at getDevBundleDir (/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.qtn91h++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:35:23)
>       at Object. (/home/epa/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.qtn91h++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cli/dev-bundle.js:176:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

Comment: It is referring to `/workspace/meteorProject/socially/.meteor/local/dev_bundle'  - do you have permission to write to this folder?

Comment: try to run it with administration permissions

Comment: You may need to perform the permission change recursively.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was a permissions issue but on a folder that has a relative link and so I did not change it, I just went to the real link and changed it, thanks –
y allso do:
sudo kate ~/.bashrc
then y add this lines

# User specific aliases and functions
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/epa/Android/Sdk/ 
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

and then execute
source ~/.bashrc